# Bios update of Thinkpad P50 bricked computer

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, bios

My system, ubuntu 18.04, wanted me to perform a bios update which I did. It rebooted, tried to perform the update and then the screen went black. I've been unable to get the computer to post and even after a cmos reset nothing happens. I'm a bit lost wrt fixing this issue and I'm afraid that I might never get the computer working again. I'm using UEFI boot (legacy, I think) with an NVME ssd.

Comment: Some other P50 threads. Toshiba Satellite P50 model number: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2163854
Turned NIC off and then booted off of USB. Was NOT an issue with any Linux distro just a quirk of the laptop.
Also had to stick with EFI boot ON, Secure Boot disabled. Wouldn't boot off of any media or HDD when mode set to CSM.
Toshiba P50 reset with pin hole on bottom
after tinkering, i found a little pinhole on the bottom of the laptop next to the RAM. used a paperclip to press it and now the BIOS is working again. 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2237148

Comment: I had the same happen to me.  Luckily it was still under warranty so I sent it to the depot to replace the system board.  Tech support suspects it may have been the fact that I accidentally left an external usb drive connected to the thunderbolt port during the update--would have been nice to have gotten a message saying the disconnect everything--or that I interrupted it when I turned it back on after I thought it was complete.  For future updates I'll either switch back to Windows, or unplug everything (except power) and leave it be for an hour before attempting to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Some *possible* solutions, things you can do to find out what's wrong:

**Get more info**

Try to find out what kind of update caused these problems. Was it really a BIOS update? Or some other firmware update,  e.g. for the Intel processor or SSD. Look through the firmware versions available at Lenovo. How did you install the update (from within the OS, and what OS? Is there still a copy of Windows on you pc? What happens when you turn the thing on? And has this changed after you tried things? Try to describe it as precisely as possible, e.g. do you hear the fans, do you hear beeps? Did you see anything at all on the screen? How long does it take?

**What have you tried so far?**

It might be that you tried more things. Have you tried booting from a CD/USB? Have you tried changing BIOS(UEFI) settings?

**Try to boot Lenovo's diagnostics and other boot tools**

Try [Lenovo's bootable diagnostics CD](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/nl/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-P-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-P50/downloads/DS025448), to find out if you can boot anything (this one was updated just last week!). If you don't have a cd-slot, you could try to make a bootable USB-drive with this image, but this might not work.
On the downloads & support webpage for your model, there are other Diagnostics tools meant for USB-drives. But those are older than the one for CD.

***Read the manual***
*(and don't take rash decisions)*

Read this [P50 Hardware Maintenance manual](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/p50_hmm_en_sp40j71944_03.pdf) as well as the [P50 User Guide](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/p50_ug_en.pdf) and follow all the troubleshooting steps in detail (e.g. what is your F2 key or power button is broken?). And write down every error / message you get. There's even a tool for Android that can recognize the error codes in beeps. 
There are many potential causes (Secure boot/unsigned drivers, RAID setups, failed driver updates. To help you, I would need to know a little more about the current state etc.

**BIOS update from CD or USB**

Just before submitting I discovered this: [Lenovo P50 BIOS update utility](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/nl/en/downloads/ds106108). You can use the windows utility (on a different pc) to create a bootable USB to update the BIOS. On the same page, there is also a link to a bootable CD. If you can boot from a CD/USB, I'd think this is your best shot. I saw a lot of recent updates on the manufacturers website (Intel AMT, BIOS) and some of them have caused trouble. If you're not the only one: make sure to check the support community on the manufacturers website.